# Is it possible to pause and resume Microsoft Cognitive SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the JavaScript version of Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk.

I want to pause the recognizer so that it won't process the response from the TTS audio.
I can call stopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop it and then create a new instance again but it is slow to have the recognizer to be available again.

Is it possible to pause and resume Microsoft Cognitive SpeechRecognizer?

```
    this.speechConfig.enableDictation();
    this.audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
    this.recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(this.speechConfig, this.audioConfig);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here is detail discussion on this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2542d0a2-fdd1-462e-a228-cd328d89a5c4/how-to-pause-speech-to-text-continuous-recognition-?forum=AzureCognitiveService. You can use Continuous Speech Recognition (>15 seconds) to run longer samples along with speech synthesis and close() the recognizer completely and the microphone will be dropped in the same manner Stop() did.

Comment: Thanks for the information.